# Alexa skill not opening when the word 'Alexa' is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, invocation

I am building a trivia skill using the sample provided. 
Under the test tab in Alexa console, when I say "Alexa, open my-skill-name" I get an audio only response (with an error sound).
But when I say "Open my-skill-name", the skill is launched.

Any help on why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dev console acts a bit differently than a physical device, so you don't need to write 'Alexa' before your skill name. Also 'open' is optional in the dev console too. You can write 'skill-name' in the console and it will work, so don't worry about it, if your skill gets invoked in dev console, it should work on the device too.

I cannot find the exact [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html#test-different-screens) talking about it, but every example in amazon testing instructions don't use invocation.